# Writing SVN changelog to file

Tags: svn, powershell

I'm trying to export the entire revision history of an SVN project to a text file (need to do it as part of an audit).

I familiar with using `svn log -r x:x -v` to look up revisions, but have no clue how to export this to a text file (I'm on Windows, and using PowerShell). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dumping text data to a file in PowerShell can be done in many ways, but the easiest for this situation is probably [`out-file`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx).

`svn log -r x:x -v | out-file -path PATH_TO_FILE`

Comment: Thanks! I also just found out I can use `svn log -r x:x -v > foo.txt`